# PhotoSwipe display only one image from Views grid form

Tags: 7, views

I created a grid view to display several node images thumbnails (3 columns, and multiple lines), and following PhotoSwipe usage found whithin the README.txt, I specified the CSS class "photoswipe-gallery" to display the field image.

Now when I click on one image from the view, I got the full sized Image as I wanted, but I can't move to the next or previous image that exist within my view grid.

Is there anybody knowing how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations, I hook (?) the views-view-grid-default.tpl.php and wrap the grid  within a:

```
<div class="photoswipe-gallery"> <table> ...</div>
```

block and now the script take correctly all images found in the grid table.

Of course I removed this class from the image field parameter.

Thanks